# Can I remove a single layer from from docker to prevent caching?

Tags: docker, caching, build

I have a long-running docker build process, so I would prefer not to disable caching for the entire build (with `--no-cache`). However, I would like to invalidate caching for a particular step.

I had a bright idea: remove the cached layer and rebuild so this has to rebuild.

I used:

```
docker build --progress=plain
```

to get hold of the sha of the cached layer:

```
#16 [stage-9  3/15] RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.lock
#16 sha256:e4ac79a1eac5702cd296ccf33a1cfa2e0c3890c77d42737dc62a3b26ac3e798e
#16 CACHED
```

But then I got this error

```
> docker rmi e4ac79a1eac5702cd296ccf33a1cfa2e0c3890c77d42737dc62a3b26ac3e798
Error: No such image: e4ac79a1eac5702cd296ccf33a1cfa2e0c3890c77d42737dc62a3b26ac3e798
```

Is there an  (easy) way of deleting this layer?

Note: For most use cases (and maybe even this one) you might like to use the [--no-cache](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) option for `docker build`

Comment: Looks like you missed the very last character of the hash (e) in the `docker rmi` command.

Answer (score 8):

Not directly possible. But can be done with some changes to your docker file.

To forcibly break the cache, you can use "build-time arguments" (ARG); changing the value of that argument breaks the cache, and every step after it, for example:

```
FROM something
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install foo bar baz ......

ARG CACHE_DATE=2016-01-01

# steps below will always be executed if `CACHE_DATE` is changed to a unique value
RUN blablabla
```

And set a new date for CACHE_DATE during build:

```
docker build --build-arg CACHE_DATE="$(date)" ....
```

details taken directly from [this github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22832).

Answer (score 3):

Theres a hacky way to do this if you'd like, and it might not work for your use case... but during the tons of QA I've done over the years for my team at [cycle.io](https://cycle.io) - I found that if I needed to control a caching layer I could move it towards the end of the Dockerfile and put a "copy" step for any arbitrary file (say a .txt file) right before it.  If you make a change to the txt file it invalidates the caching of all following steps.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, with docker, you only have the option of using `--no-cache` to completely turn off using the cache.

If you're happy editing the dockerfile before building the image, then the easiest way to go about this would be to add another step to the image.

While I've never tried doing this, if you only want to use the cache up to a certain point, it may be worth seeing if [creating your own base/parent image](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/) is something that would work in your case. The downside to this is you would have two dockerfiles and two images but you could on your first dockerfile (the base/parent image) use the cache but then on your second dockerfile use the `--no-cache` option.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can remove by this command:

```
docker rm e4ac79a1eac5702cd296ccf33a1cfa2e0c3890c77d42737dc62a3b26ac3e798
```

Because you are still using the same image and only different containers.

Comment: `docker rm` complains `No such container`.

Answer (score 0):

To invalidate cache for a particular step use `ARGS` before that step

```
ARGS anchor cached
RUN .... # step to
```

then pass different value each time

`` docker run --build-arg ANCHOR="`date`" . ``

Comment: That requires editing the Docker file unless it happens to already have an ARGS at that step. If you are going to edit the Docker file, then you can do all sorts of things to cause the file to regenerate, like adding a step `RUN echo cachebuster`. The question is how do you remove the cached layer without altering the Dockerfile or producing a different image than you would get if you built with `--no-cache`.

Answer (score -2):

Docker creates container images using layers. Each command that is found in a Dockerfile creates a new layer. Each layer contains the filesystem changes to the image for the state before the execution of the command and the state after the execution of the command.

Docker uses a layer cache to optimize and speed up the process of building Docker images.

Docker Layer Caching mainly works on the RUN, COPY and ADD commands, which will be explained in more detail next.